# How do you (safely) test a GFCI circuit breaker from the outlet when the circuit has no ground?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, gfci

I know I can press the "test" button on the breaker in the panel.

But I want to double-check that there isn't some strange wiring situation hidden in the walls that could prevent the GFCI from tripping properly. I have used an outlet GFCI tester but it tests by using ground, which I don't have (hence new GFCI breakers).

Theoretically I could test by sticking a fork in the socket, but even if I had a controlled way to do that (e.g. plug with wires tied together and insulated well), I am nervous about a situation like that causing a rapid heat build-up and damaging/melting things, or starting a fire.

One idea I had was to take my GFCI tester and wire it to an outlet so that the tester's ground goes to the outlet neutral. Then pressing the button on the tester would do the normal test, but using hot/neutral. Would that work and be safe?

Comment: The fork test would not only be dangerous (obviously) but would actually only test the over-current protection and **not** the GFCI. Ground to another receptacle's (different circuit) neutral is an interesting thought, thought it doesn't seem like a terribly safe idea (conceptually good).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a three to two prong adapter and run a wire from an actual ground to the little tab, then use your button tester.

Comment: Awesome. So simple, and easy.

Comment: Boom! That's the answer.